# select certain videos for youtube-dl using format codes

Tags: youtube-dl

So I have youtube-dl setup and am trying to "automate" a way that I download videos. I have got it mostly setup however I need a way to be able to only select videos that have a format code starting with "en" and ignore the ones beginning with other characters. The output of the -F list is below.

```
format code     extension  resolution note
en_br-hls-1249  mp4        640x360    1249k , avc1.4d001e, mp4a.40.2
ja_br-hls-1452  mp4        640x360    1452k , avc1.4d001e, mp4a.40.2
en_br-hls-1762  mp4        854x480    1762k , avc1.4d001f, mp4a.40.2
ja_br-hls-2067  mp4        854x480    2067k , avc1.4d001f, mp4a.40.2
en_br-hls-2991  mp4        1280x720   2991k , avc1.640029, mp4a.40.2
ja_br-hls-3513  mp4        1280x720   3513k , avc1.640029, mp4a.40.2
en_br-hls-5857  mp4        1920x1080  5857k , avc1.640029, mp4a.40.2
ja_br-hls-6904  mp4        1920x1080  6904k , avc1.640029, mp4a.40.2 (best)
```

As you can see from the list above the "best" is currently on the format that begins with ja and sometimes it reverses so the best is listed as "en". What I want is a way for it to always select the best "en" stream and not the ja which it currently does when I feed it the "-f best" variable.

Any help would help as I'm not exactly sure how I do this, or even if there is a way in youtube-dl by default. if not then a way to make it do what I want in the site code itself could work.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

So it seems I have found out how I didn't remove this so it gives others who are having the same issue as me to find it.

So with the format selecting you are able to add filters to them, I was initially trying to use the --match-filter variable but all I needed to actually do was.

```
-f "best[format_id^=en]"
```

This basically tells youtube-dl to only use formats were the id begins with "en"